# Enable UIiStatusBar for iPad, disable for iPhone in Universal iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal-binary, uistatusbar

I have a Universal iOS application, I want the status bar (UIStatusBar) to appear when the app is installed on the iPad but not when installed on the iPhone.

Currently my solution is to set UIStatusBarHidden in the app-info.plist to true (which affects both versions) and then re-enable it in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if the device is iPad. This kind of works, but I want the status bar to appear when the app is still loading (showing the default screen) for iPad, and not for iPhone.

Is there any way to accomplish this? (I've tried adding an iPad specific key/value UIStatusBarHidden~ipad but that didn't work)

Comment: Strange, I just tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Got it working, looks like I forgot to set the value type in the .plist to a BOOLEAN, which is why it didn't work before.

Comment: I used UIStatusBarHidden~ipad :) Glad you figured out yourself. Go ahead and post your solution in 24h and accept it for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up your App-Info.plist file and make sure to view raw key/values, add a new row and call it: UIStatusBarHidden~ipad, set the value type to Boolean, and set the value to NO. You can now have UIStatusBarHidden set to YES for iPhone as well.